# How to remove the decimals(milliseconds) from Elapsed time in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, math

I have an elapsed time functionality but the elapsed time gets printed in decimals. Example `10.102` seconds when I want it to be just `10` seconds. How do I achieve that?

```
var startTime = new Date();


//Stopwatch 
sleep (30000);
var endTime = new Date();
var seconds = (endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000;
print("Elapsed Time is " + seconds + " seconds");
```

Comment: The `Math.round()` function will never return a value with a fractional part.

Comment: @Pointy So, how do I get around this problem?

Comment: You can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary

Comment: @Pointy sorry, i realised that it was the wrong code, I have edited the question!

Comment: @AliEsmailpor I'm very new. Where exactly would i use Math.round?

Comment: Just use `Date.now()` over creating a new date object then converting to an epoch timestamp.

Comment: @Alex where exactly? I edited the question, so I don't know if you're answering for the previous code or this one

Comment: The code you originally had was producing the correct answer, once you swapped out `new Date()` with `Date.now()`. Why did you change it?

Answer (score 0):

I really love this method of displaying my time from seconds -> 00:00:00 or 00:00 or 00; some more formatting needed.

```js
    function ToHHMMSS(secs) {
        let sec_num = parseInt(secs, 10);
        let hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
        let minutes = Math.floor(sec_num / 60) % 60;
        let seconds = sec_num % 60;
        return [hours, minutes, seconds].map(t => t < 10 ? "0" + t : t).filter((t, i) => t !== "00" || i > 0).join(":");
    }

    console.log(ToHHMMSS(10.2));
    console.log(ToHHMMSS(10.32));
    console.log(ToHHMMSS(10.2));
    console.log(ToHHMMSS(11110.2));
    console.log(ToHHMMSS(10.2));
    console.log(ToHHMMSS(310.2));
    console.log(ToHHMMSS(120.2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [learning some JavaScript](https://www.learn-js.org/). There are a ton of free resources.

```js
var startTime = new Date();


function timer() {
  var endTime = new Date();
  var timeDiff = endTime - startTime;
  timeDiff /= 1000;
  var seconds = Math.round(timeDiff % 60);
  console.log("Elapsed Time is " + seconds + " seconds");
}


//Stopwatch 
setTimeout(timer, 2523);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt()` to keep the seconds only.

```js
let date1 = new Date();
let date2 = new Date();
date1.setMilliseconds(date1.getMilliseconds() - 3712);
let diff = date2 - date1; // in ms

console.log(date1.getTime());
console.log(date2.getTime());
console.log(`${parseInt(diff / 1000)} seconds`); // "3 seconds"
```